# What is the meaning of "differences of degree and not of kind"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Trying to get the idea from the sentence.

> What I am saying is these are only differences of degree and not of
>   kind, as in labelling a minority as religious or political or social.

What is the meaning of "differences of degree and not of kind"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning behind this would be that the differences are not of *sort*, *type*, or *style*, **but** of *level*, *stage*, or *class*.

Basically, 'degree' and 'kind' are generalizing words for different types of other words.

> - Cats, dogs, and mice are **kinds** of animals.
> - And first-, second-, and third-degree burns are **degrees** of burns.

To differentiate things by kind would mean to contrast or compare them.

Differentiating by degree would mean comparing things within a group of the same things, but on different stages/levels.

Answer (score 7):

A difference of degree is a difference of magnitude, between two things that are otherwise of the same type. The difference between a small dog and a large dog is one of degree. So is the difference between a light tap and a heavy blow. A difference of kind is a difference of type or category. The difference between a dog and a cat is a difference of kind. If you are quoting from the Sashi Kumar interview on India Abroad, then he is saying that attacks in India on political, ethnic, caste, or religious minorities are all the same kind of thing, and not different in nature.

> degree   noun (AMOUNT) ​ (an) amount or level of something
>
> kind noun a group with similar
>   characteristics, or a particular type

[Degree](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/degree)
[Kind](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind)

Answer (score -2):

All **kinds of** virtues (honesty, kindness, compassion, loyalty, morality) and vices (kama, krodha, lobha, moha, mad and matsara) are present in the humans, the difference lies in the extent or **the degree** of these virtues and vices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Suhas, that's a nice example sentence, but doesn't answer the question. Can you expand on your answer? Welcome to ELU!